How to find the combination of numbers that sum (or closer) to a given target?
My input is a list of dicts that correspond to tasks  :
tasks = [
    {'ID': 'ID_001', 'VOLUME': 50, 'STATUS': 'ENDED_OK'},
    {'ID': 'ID_002', 'VOLUME': 10, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},
    {'ID': 'ID_003', 'VOLUME': 10, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},
    {'ID': 'ID_004', 'VOLUME': 20, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},
    {'ID': 'ID_005', 'VOLUME': 10, 'STATUS': 'ONGOING'},
    {'ID': 'ID_006', 'VOLUME': 10, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},
    {'ID': 'ID_007', 'VOLUME': 25, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},
]

My goal is to find a random combination of tasks where:

The number of waiting tasks is exactly as specified
The total volume is as close as possible to a given target volume

For that I made the code below but it's extremely slow in my real dataset (~10k tasks) and I also don't trust it because I feel like sometimes it doesn't give the right combination.
import itertools


def find_combination(tasks, number_ids, target_volume=50):
    waiting_tasks = [task for task in tasks if task['STATUS'] == 'WAITING']

    sorted_tasks = sorted(waiting_tasks, key=lambda x: x['VOLUME'], reverse=True)

    closest_combination = []
    closest_volume_diff = float('inf')

    for combination in itertools.combinations(sorted_tasks, number_ids):
        total_volume = sum(task['VOLUME'] for task in combination)
        volume_diff = abs(total_volume - target_volume)

        if volume_diff < closest_volume_diff:
            closest_combination = combination
            closest_volume_diff = volume_diff

        if volume_diff == 0:
            break

    return [task['ID'] for task in closest_combination], sum(
        task['VOLUME'] for task in closest_combination
    )

ids_selected, total_volume = find_combination(tasks, 3, target_volume=50)
print(f'Selected IDs: {ids_selected}, Total Volume: {total_volume}')
# Selected IDs: ['ID_007', 'ID_004', 'ID_002'], Total Volume: 55

Do you guys have an idea on how to fix my code ?

Constraints of the problem

tasks: list[dict] is of size 10**4
number_ids can be from 1 to 10,
target_volume ranges from 50 to a max of 1000
task['VOLUME'] is always an integer between 1 to 300.


Do you have to code this yourself? Or could you use Python to solve this as an optimization problem?

What are your real volumes and number_ids like?

What's an example where it doesn't give the right combination?

@nocomment, the real volumes range from 1 to 300 and the ids (that are unique) are strings of length 10. And for your second question, I remember when I was doing the tests I had a feeling to not getting the right combination with some values passed to the function find_combination. If I can't make an example, I will delete the part where I say that in my post.

And number_ids? (In your example it's 3.) Also, are he volumes integers, and what is your target volume like?

number_ids can be from 1 to 10 and the volumes are always integers > 0. The target volume is also flexible and ranges from 50 to a max of 1000.

Ok, then DP looks appropriate and I think Js King can fix their code.

@nocomment, just for the context, the two parameters of the function are passed by two sliders of a web application. The user can adjust those at real time and must get a result in a relatively short period of time. If you can provide a solution with dynamic programming, I will be very grateful

wouldn't be easier, instead of sorting the list of dict, making a dict with key the volume and values list of ids? Then the problem is reduced to find the best way to decompose the target volume (or an approx of it)

@cards, the list tasks comes from a dataframe. If a reshaping is needed, I'm ok with it.

You say you want to find a random combination but there's no attempt for randomness in your code. Did you actually mean it?


You can group the same volume or similar volumes and avoid unnecessary combinations. For example, use a pre-sorted list of unique volumes or use a heuristic to exclude extreme values.

Can stop exploring combinations once you exceed the target volume.


Here's updated code.
from itertools import combinations

def find_combination(tasks, number_ids, target_volume=50):
    waiting_tasks = [task for task in tasks if task['STATUS'] == 'WAITING']

    # Edge case: not enough tasks to choose from
    if len(waiting_tasks) < number_ids:
        return [], 0

    # Dynamic programming setup
    dp = {0: []}  # key: volume, value: task IDs for that volume
    
    # Iterate over each task and update DP table
    for task in waiting_tasks:
        task_id, task_vol = task['ID'], task['VOLUME']
        
        # Make a copy of current DP state to update with the current task
        new_dp = dp.copy()

        # Update the DP table for combinations that include the current task
        for current_vol, current_comb in dp.items():
            new_vol = current_vol + task_vol
            if new_vol not in new_dp or len(new_dp[new_vol]) > len(current_comb) + 1:
                new_dp[new_vol] = current_comb + [task]

        dp = new_dp

    # Find the closest volume to target with exactly `number_ids` tasks
    closest_combination = []
    closest_volume_diff = float('inf')

    for vol, comb in dp.items():
        if len(comb) == number_ids:
            volume_diff = abs(vol - target_volume)
            if volume_diff < closest_volume_diff:
                closest_combination = comb
                closest_volume_diff = volume_diff

    return [task['ID'] for task in closest_combination], sum(task['VOLUME'] for task in closest_combination)


Where is your code doing 1. or 2.? I don't see it.

The code isn't right, for example find_combination([     {'ID': 'ID_001', 'VOLUME': 10, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},     {'ID': 'ID_002', 'VOLUME': 20, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'},     {'ID': 'ID_003', 'VOLUME': 30, 'STATUS': 'WAITING'}, ], 2, target_volume=30) returns (['ID_001', 'ID_003'], 40).

A brute force approach (computational expensive)
The combinatorial part is the bottle neck of the program. My approach is to solve that part with a list of integers instead of a list of dictionaries as in OP. No sorting is used.
Here a help function to understand the size of the computations
import math


def find_combination_simulation(tasks, V=80, N=5, batch_size=10**4, time_per_batch=10):
    n_combos = math.comb(len(tasks), N)
    n_batches = n_combos // batch_size
    time_exec = n_batches * time_per_batch
    print(f"n tasks = {len(tasks)} {N = } {V = }")
    print(f"Maximal Amount of combinations: {math.comb(len(tasks), len(tasks) // 2):_}".replace('_', "'"))
    print(f"Amount of combinations:         {n_combos:_}".replace('_', "'"))
    print(f"{n_batches:_} batches of size {batch_size:_}".replace('_', "'"))
    print(f"Estimated time: {time_exec/60**2:.3f}hours, {time_exec/60:.3f}min, {time_exec:.3f}s")


V = 80
N = 4
batch_size=1e3

find_combination_simulation(tasks, V, N, batch_size, time_per_batch=1e-3)

Output
n tasks = 100 N = 4 V = 80
Maximal Amount of combinations: 100'891'344'545'564'193'334'812'497'256   # <- when N = V//2 (Catalan numbers)
Amount of combinations:         3'921'225
3'921.0 batches of size 1'000.0
Estimated time: 0.003hours, 0.182min, 10.902s

So, when the numbers of tasks is of the size of 10k the amount of iterations could be just too huge! To slightly reduce the data I would suggest to do some basic statistical operations to understand how the data are distributed (location & spread) and remove tails/middle part... or other.
Version 1: global iteration (no batching)
from collections import Counter
import itertools as it
from operator import itemgetter


V = 80 #             ideal value of volume
N = 4 #              amount of tasks to consider for the approximation
tasks:list[dict] = # from the problem

# waiting_tasks
waiting_tasks = filter(lambda d: d['STATUS'] == "WAITING", tasks)
# decouple the dicts
ids, vs = zip(*map(itemgetter('ID', 'VOLUME'), waiting_tasks))

# find the best volume combination
best_v = float('inf')
best_v_combo = tuple()
for combo in it.combinations(vs, N):
    dv = abs(sum(combo) - V) # difference of volume
    if dv < best_v:
        best_v = dv
        best_v_combo = combo
        if dv == 0:
            break

# find the ids of the best combination
best_ids = []
best_combo_multi_set = Counter(best_v_combo) # similar to a sort + groupby approach
for v, multiplicity in best_combo_multi_set.items():
    k = -1
    # get index for repeated values
    for _ in range(multiplicity):
        k = vs.index(v, k+1)
        best_ids.append(ids[k])

best_ids = tuple(best_ids)

# summary
print(f"{sum(best_v_combo)}/{V} error {abs(sum(best_v_combo) - V)} with {N} tasks")
print("ids", best_ids)
print("combo", best_v_combo)

Output
65/80 error 15 with 4 tasks
ids ('ID_002', 'ID_003', 'ID_004', 'ID_007')
combo (10, 10, 20, 25)

Version 2: with batches (Python3.12 due to itertools.batched)
Find a good batch_size by experimenting a bit with the data. Start with small values and increase them very gently until a good compromise is found.
def find_combination(tasks, V=80, N=5, batch_size=10**4):
    # V: ideal value of volume
    # N: amount of tasks to consider for the approximation
    print(f"Amount of combinations: {math.comb(len(tasks), N):_}".replace('_', "'"))
    print(f"{math.comb(len(tasks), N) // batch_size:_} batches of size {batch_size:_}".replace('_', "'"))

    def _find_best_volume(tasks:list[int], V:int) -> tuple[tuple[int], int]:
        # find the best volume combination
        best_v = float('inf')
        best_v_combo = tuple()

        for combo in tasks:
            dv = abs(sum(combo) - V) # difference of volume (error)
            if dv < best_v:
                best_v = dv
                best_v_combo = combo
                if dv == 0:
                    break
        return best_v_combo, dv

    def _find_best_ids(combo:tuple[int], ids:tuple[str]) -> tuple[str]:
        # find the ids of the best combination
        best_ids = []
        # similar to a sort + groupby approach
        for v, multiplicity in Counter(combo).items():
            k = -1
            # get index for repeated values
            for _ in range(multiplicity):
                k = vs.index(v, k+1)
                best_ids.append(ids[k])

        return best_ids

    # waiting_tasks
    waiting_tasks = filter(lambda d: d['STATUS'] == "WAITING", tasks)
    # decouple the dicts
    ids, vs = zip(*map(itemgetter('ID', 'VOLUME'), waiting_tasks))

    best_IDs, best_COMBO = ids, vs
    best_ERROR = abs(sum(best_COMBO) - V)
    # check value intial iteration 
    if best_ERROR == 0:
        print(f"{tuple(best_IDs) = }")
        print(f"{best_COMBO = }")
        return

    combos = it.combinations(vs, N)
    for batch in it.batched(combos, int(batch_size)): # int-cast is needed because 1e4 is a notation for a float!

        best_v_combo, error = _find_best_volume(batch, V)
        # updating condition between batches - only if minimal error-condition is satisfied 
        if best_ERROR > error:
            best_COMBO = best_v_combo
            best_IDs = _find_best_ids(best_v_combo, ids)
            best_ERROR = error

            # done, found best possible solution
            if best_ERROR == 0: break

    print(f"{tuple(best_IDs) = }")
    print(f"{best_COMBO = }")

Version 3 (just ideas): extend version 2 with a multithreads functionality
Compute batches in "parallel" with special cares with common resources such as best_ERROR, best_IDs, best_COMBO.

An exact approach (fast but a solution does not always exist)
This method is mathematical oriented and based on the theory of integer partition, i.e. counting all possible ways to write an integer 3 = 1 + 2 = 1 + 1 + 1.
The implementation for counting integer partitions

of the same size is taken from this answer,
of any size more can be found here.

The partitions are generated recursively and the execution can be boosted with memoization techniques.
(I think) Every number V has at least a natural than integer partition of size N, and this partition has to satisfy also the constraints given by the data tasks. So, depending on the data, a solution may exist or may not, for ex it fails with V=120 and N = 30.
This lake of solvability could be relaxed by try to solve a slightly a different problem, for example by changing V to V+1 and/or V-1 and check these are solvable. If not then repeat the relaxation step. Otherwise try to relax N or, in case, both.
from collections import Counter
from functools import cache


@cache
def partition(N, size):
    if size == 1 :
        yield (N,)                    # base case, only 1 part
        return
    for a in range(1, N//size + 1):   # smaller part followed by
        for p in partition(N - a*size, size - 1): # equal or larger ones
            yield (a, *(n+a for n in p)) 


V = 1200 #                     ideal value of volume
N = 30 #                       amount of tasks to consider for the approximation
waiting_tasks:list[int] = #    from the problem


best_combo = None
c_tasks = Counter(waiting_tasks) # this Counter could be replace with a waiting_tasks.count(i) in the innermost conditional block
for p in partition(V, N):    
    for i, multiplicy in Counter(filter(None, p)).items():
        if i in c_tasks:
            if c_tasks[i] >= multiplicy:
                best_combo = tuple(p)
                break

if best_combo:
    print(f"Exact volume of {sum(best_combo)} out of {N}:", best_combo)    
    # find the ids of the best combination
    # [see previous implementation with best_combo = best_v_combo or use _find_best_ids]

else:
    print('Could not find exact combination of volumes.')

Output
Exact volume of 1200 out of 30: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 396, 397)


@VERBOSE let me know if there is a time improvement. If still too slow maybe a multithread approach could be a possibility(? )

just to be clear: the code works perfectly and it is quite performant. Tested with 1000 dicts and different number_ids

Notice that if l = len(waiting_tasks) is 10**4,  the amount of combinations, len(str(math.comb(l, 3))), is a number with 12 digits and, depending on the value of number_ids, it may grow upto 3000 digits

If I add their tasks to your code, it only prints "45/80 error 35 with 2 tasks", not an actual combination. If I change V and N back to their 50 and 3, I get ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple.

the ValueError is now fixed and output more readable
